# Create a Dynamic Checkbox Validation in Angular With Data from API

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I have a function that displays a list from an API:

```
displayEventTicketDetails() {
  this.Service
      .getEventTicketDetails().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.eventTicketDetails = data.map(ticket => ticket.ticket_name);
        console.log(this.eventTicketDetails);
      });
  }
```

This is the result from the function above:
`["Regular", "VIP", "Table", "Testing", "Cabana"]`

Here is how the form array is declared:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.composeMessage = this.fb.group({
      ticket: new FormArray([])
    });
```

Then I use this function below to track if the check boxes are checked

```
  onChange(event: any, isChecked: boolean){
      const control = <FormArray>this.composeMessage.controls.ticket;
      if(isChecked){
        control.push(new FormControl(event))
      } else{
        const index = control.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === event);
        control.removeAt(index)
      }
  }
```

Then finally in my ts file, here is my onsubmit function that submits the data on the form:

```
 submitComposeMessage() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.composeMessage.invalid) {
      return;
    } 
    const ticket = this.f.ticket.value;
    this.Service
      .createMessage(
        ticket)
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          if (res.err) {
            this.toaster.errorToastr(res.message, null, { toastTimeout: 5000 });
            return false;
          }
          this.toaster.successToastr(res.message, null, { toastTimeout: 5000 });
          console.log("Message successfully created");
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }
```

So in my Html file here is my input field:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let event of eventTicketDetails; let i = index"  >
  <label class="w-checkbox checkbox-field" >
    <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="{{i}}"
    name="checkbox-9"
    class="w-checkbox-input checkbox"
    (change)="onChange(event, $event.target.checked)"
    [checked]="composeMessage.controls.ticket.value.indexOf(event)>=0">
      <span class="no-margin w-form-label">{{event}}</span>
  </label>
</ng-container>
```

With that loop, I'm able to get this result
[image]

So, I need help with two things:

1). I want all the checkbox to be checked by default when the page loads at first instance.
2). I want to validate the checkbox to ensure at least one checkbox is checked on submission.

I'll appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

change Id to something like this

```
id="ticket{{i}}"
```

In this method write like this and call displayEventTicketDetails on ngOnit. This will check all the values:

```
     displayEventTicketDetails() {
      this.Service
          .getEventTicketDetails().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.eventTicketDetails = data.map(ticket =>ticket.ticket_name);
        setTimeout(() => {
             for(var i= 0;i < this.evenTicketDetails.length ; i++){  
              var id = "ticket" + i;
            (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).checked = true;   
                console.log(this.eventTicketDetails);
           }, 500);

          });
      }



  2. In submit method write something like this
    submitComposeMessage() {
                for(var i= 0;i < this.evenTicketDetails.length ; i++){  
                 var id = "ticket" + i;
                var resval =  (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).value;   
                   if(resval){

 // this will check atleast one value is checked and if it true we are coming 
                    out of the loop and performing other operations..
                i = this.evenTicketDetails.length;

               } 
               else{
                // show error message or block from going forward..
                }

             });

          }
```

This will solve your issues.

Comment: For some weird reasons, I got this error ```Cannot set property 'checked' of null```

Comment: How are you assigning id’s in the HTML?

Comment: This way ```id="ticket{{i}}"```

Comment: okay I got it I updated the answer. Please add setimeout function to your code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only show validation message after submit, I would suggest the following, where we instead iterate the formarray in template, initially set all checked (as that is what you wish). We would listen to `valueChanges` of the formarray, but filter out as long as form is not submitted. We would introduce a new variable, for example `isEmpty`, which based on we would show/hide validation message. So all in all....

TS:

```ts
isEmpty = false;
submitted = false;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  const ctrls = this.eventTicketDetails.map(control => this.fb.control(true));
  this.composeMessage = this.fb.group({
    ticket: this.fb.array(ctrls)
  });

  this.tickets.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(() => !!this.submitted)
  ).subscribe((value) => {
    value.some(x => x === true) ? this.isEmpty = false : this.isEmpty = true;
  })
}

get tickets() {
  return this.composeMessage.get("ticket") as FormArray;
}

onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  const selectedTickets = this.tickets.value
    .map((checked, i) => (checked ? this.eventTicketDetails[i] : null))
    .filter(value => !!value);
  selectedTickets.length ? this.isEmpty = false : this.isEmpty = true
}
```

HTML:

```html
<label formArrayName="ticket" *ngFor="let t of tickets.controls; index as i">
  <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
  {{eventTicketDetails[i]}}
</label>
<small *ngIf="isEmpty">Choose at least one checkbox</small>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtkbfj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: This actually works if the values are staticlike this: eventTicketDetails = ["Regular", "VIP", "Table", "Testing", "Cabana"];

But the problem comes when I try passing the values from the data coming from my API in this function 
``` displayEventTicketDetails() {
  this.Service
      .getEventTicketDetails().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.eventTicketDetails = data.map(ticket => ticket.ticket_name);
        console.log(this.eventTicketDetails);
      });
  }```

I get an error that says ```Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Comment: well you need set the formcontrols in the callback (subscribe). The above was just a sample with static data.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that now.